# One line solution with projective geometry

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, geometric-transformation

I am trying to solve the following problem

***Let $A,B,C,D$ be four points in the plane.Let lines $AC$ and $BD$ meet at $P$ , lines
$AB$ and $CD$ meet at $Q$, and lines $BC$ and $DA$ meet at $R$. Let line through $P$ parallel to $QR$ meet lines $AB$ and $CD$ at $X$ and $Z$. Show that $P$ is the midpoint of $XZ$.***

There is a hint from the author that it can be solved in one line using projective geometry and specifically perspectivity at $Q$.

I can't find this one liner does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: ... what is $Y$? Is that supposed to be a $Z$?

Comment: If so, I have a fact that *might* be helpful (although I don't know, maybe something easier suffices): I can't remember the exact ordering, but $P$ is the midpoint of $XZ$ iff (some permutation I can't remember) of $X,P, Z, \infty$ is a harmonic set. Maybe you can show that $X,P, Z,\infty$ is an image of a harmonic set via a perspectivity at $Q$? Maybe we need to construct a line between $Q$ and $P$...

Comment: Just consider the pencil $Q(A,D;P,R)=-1$ and intersect it with $XY$, as in my solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $S=PQ\cap DA$, and let $P_{\infty}=XY\cap QR$. Then $-1=(A,D;S,R)\stackrel{Q}{=}(X,Y;P,P_{\infty})$, so $P$ is the midpoint of $\overline{XY}$.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks a lot.

Comment: aha, so my idea about using a harmonic set of points works out? Cool. There aren't any $Y$'s in the problem statement any more either, so it might be good to adjust notation to become consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the projective involution (maybe it is called perspectivity, I don't remember the terminology) with center $P$ and axis $QR$ which fixes line $QR$ pointwise and maps point $A$ to $C$. Then line $AB$ is mapped to $DC$ and $AD$ to $BC$. Consequently $X$ is mapped to $Z$. Since $XZ$ is parallel to the axis $QR$, the center $P$ is the midpoint of $XZ$.

I write a bit more than average (it's just me, I am a bit wordy), but I believe this should be the spirit of the proof.

Comment: That is much better than what I thought! I was gonna assign the points homogenous coordinates and then calculate the cross ratio with the help of resulting equation of line.

Comment: @ShashwatAsthana Thank you for the acknowledgement.